# Rerouting an external Dryer Vent

Tags: dryer, vent

The dryer vent in our apartment unit exits on the ceiling of our balcony and leaves lint everywhere. What's the best way to attach a dryer duct to this vent so I can redirect it off the side of the balcony instead of having it blowing lint all over our balcony??

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with the dryer lint trap.

Comment: Rental or owned?

Comment: Why does it look like the grille only covers half of that hole in the ceiling? Can you post another pic that shows that ceiling area better?